# How to send text field value to another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a UIViewController with a text Field and a button . When the user click the button , i want to move to a TableViewCotroller and send the value of the text field to the table view . I use this code
:

```
StatusTableViewController *statuttableview =[[StatusTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];
```

It work but i dont know how i will access to the text field value from  StatusTableViewController .
Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go a little deeper into the basics....
You have to add a `NSString` property to the `StatusTableViewController` and set it in a custom init or with its setter after initialization.

in `StatusTableViewController.h` do something like

```
NSString *myText;
```

...

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myText;
```

....

and/or

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibname bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle text:(NSString *)text;
```

in StatusTableViewController.m do

```
@synthsize myText;
```

and/or

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibname bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle text:(NSString *)text
{
   if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibname bundle:bundle])
   {
     self.myText = text;
   }
}
```

and in  you code call the custom init or

> statuttableview.myText = text

.

Comment: For NSString properties you should really use (nonatomic, copy) as it could be a mutable string....

Answer (score 0):

get the value from textfield and and send that to string placed with property and syntesize in
StatusTableViewController controller    and use like this

```
StatusTableViewController *statuttableview =[[StatusTableViewController     alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusTableViewController" bundle:nil];

statuttableview.textValue=valueLocal;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one NSString *str (variable) in StatusTableViewController.h file and do property,synthesize it.
After that do following code in your current controller,

```
StatusTableViewController *statuttableview =[[StatusTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusTableViewController" bundle:nil];
statuttableview.str=textfield.text;
[statuttableview.str retain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];
```