# How to send the text from textfield to another class?

Tags: iphone, class, textfield

In my app Iphone, I want to do a simple thing like : I have a GroupDetailViewController with a text Field and a button. When user press the button I want to send the text from textfield to another class ItemViewController and set this text to a label. I have no idea how can I do this. I am new on Iphone,I have done just some tutorials. I have looked here : [How to send text field value to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059128/how-to-send-text-field-value-to-another-class) but I dont understand the answer. Can anyone explain me or give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that your second class is **SecondViewController**.
Now in SecondViewController declare one `NSString` and set its properties.

**SecondViewController.h**

```
NSString *strTextValue;  

....  

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *strTextValue;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
@synthesize strTextValue;
```

Now in  *GroupDetailViewController*, on button touch event, put the value from **textfield** in `strTextValue`.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonMethod:(id)sender
{
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
controller.strTextValue = [txtField text];  
//Navigate to SecondViewController
}
```

Put `strTextValue` in label created in *SecondViewController*

**SecondViewController.m**

```
lbl.text = strTextValue;
```

Comment: Where should I put lbl.text = strTextValue; and how can I navigate to the other class? I know that this could seems trivial to you but I'm really newish to this and I can't figure out where to put those lines.

Comment: Put lbl.text = strTextValue; in viewDidLoad or better put it in ViewWillAppear.

Comment: You have to take a UINavigationController for this.

Comment: And then write [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Quick Solution:

Create a shared application delegate and set the value to a string in delegate and reuse it.
1) create an NSString variable say passVal and synthesize it in youtAppDelegate file.
2) In GroupDetailViewController

```
yourAppDelegate *del=[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate];
del.passVal=textField.text;
```

3) In ItemViewController

```
yourAppDelegate *del=[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate];
label.text=del.passVal;
```