# What method is called after [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];?

Tags: iphone, methods, viewwillappear

I have this code :

```
-(IBAction)OkButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"BTN OK");
    RecherchePartenaireTableView *recherchePartenaireTableView=[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc]init];
    recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext=textFieldCode.text;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and after I press ok I see in console the message "BTN OK" and nothing else. In class  RecherchePartenaireTableView I have the methods viewWillAppear, viewDidload... and a NSLog message for each method. What method is called after [`self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to set a property of class `RecherchePartenaireTableView`, which is on the navigation stack already then you are doing it wrong by creating a new instance of it.

You should be getting back the instance from navigationController stack.

Change

```
RecherchePartenaireTableView *recherchePartenaireTableView=[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc]init];
recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext=textFieldCode.text;
```

To

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
RecherchePartenaireTableView *recherchePartenaireTableViewVC = (RecherchePartenaireTableView *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
recherchePartenaireTableViewVC.mytext=textFieldCode.text;
```

`viewDidAppear` method will be called on the class you pushed the view from.

Comment: I found this solution [navigationController viewWillAppear:YES]; on viewDidLoad

Comment: Why textFiledCode.text is null? how can I take the text from a textField?...now I have and this problem : on viewWillappear mytext is null and I don't know why :|

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? Set a property(myText) of class `RecherchePartenaireTableView` from the class(class your button was on) that was pushed ontop of it?

Comment: In RecherchePartenaireTableView I have the property @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mytext; In RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController I have this : -(IBAction)OkButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"BTN Ok");
    
    RecherchePartenaireTableView *recherchePartenaireTableView=[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc] init];
    recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext=cellText;
    NSLog(@"jjjjjj %@",recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext);
    [self.recherchePartenaireTableView.tableviewrecherchepartenaire reloadData];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: The problem is that on viewwillAppear myText is null..why?

Comment: See edited answer for the changes you need to made. If it's null on viewWillAppear, try it on viewDidAppear.

Comment: because you are recreating a new instance of RecherchePartenaireTableView class, everytime you do perfrom your IBAction, fist of all this is a memory leak as you are not releasing your object and creating it again and again, rather you should have a property RecherchePartenaireTableView * recherchePartenaireTableView on RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController, and just set the text when IBAction is performed, (also you should reload your table in setter for myText in RecherchePartenaireTableView)

Comment: if I don't put RecherchePartenaireTableView *recherchePartenaireTableView=[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc] init]; in my IBAction, recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext is null after recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext=cellText...

Comment: And on viewWillAppear it is still null

Comment: Can you provide me an example ?

Comment: Ok, so `RecherchePartenaireTableView` is a UITableView not a UIViewController. Firstly created a NSString property on the VC that the tableview is on. Set this NSString during your IBAction. And load this string to your cell on your cellForRowAtIndex path. Reload your tableview everytime viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Gabrielle what is this myText? Please be more specify in what you are trying to do.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mytext; on RecherchePartenaireTableView

Comment: I tried to use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076762/how-to-send-the-text-from-textfield-to-another-class

Comment: @RecherchePartenaireTableView is a ViewController or UITableView? You really need to follow some naming conversion. I am confused by your namings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3660/discussion-between-gabrielle-and-matakazer)

Comment: RecherchePartenaireTableView is a ViewController

Comment: Did you try my answer? I should work. Try `NSLog(@"%@", self.mytext")` during viewDidAppear. You might have missed out `self.mytext = [[NSString alloc] init]; during viewDidLoad at RecherchePartenairTableView(viewController)`. Don't forget to do `self.mytext = nil` during dealloc.

Comment: You right...I forgot self.mytext = [[NSString alloc] init]; ...I put NSLog(@"%@", self.mytext") during viewDidAppear, but nothing is show. :(

Comment: Please do an NSlog on recherchePartenaireTableViewVC just before the statement of setting the property. What does it return? I forget an autorelease statement when we init mytext. `self.mytext = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: I have this: -(IBAction)OkButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"BTN Ok");
    
   recherchePartenaireTableView=[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"before %@",recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext);
    recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext=cellText;
    NSLog(@"after %@",recherchePartenaireTableView.mytext);
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end

Comment: before I get null and after I get the cellText

Comment: Do a NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]); You can't do `[[RecherchePartenaireTableView alloc] init];`. It's a different instance. Therefore it wouldn't be reflected back when you popViewController.

Comment: I have a little question: how can I take the text from a textField? I used [textField text] and I get null

Comment: No problem. Anyway, you should learn to follow naming conversion. UIViewController should end with ViewController. So your RecherchePartenaireTableView should be RecherchePartenaireTableViewViewController instead. It's a good practice to follow. Makes troubleshooting and coding easier.

Comment: You need to create a UITextField during interface. `IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;` Make sure the textField is linked up properly on interface builder.

Comment: IDK if using `textField.text` would make a differences. I personally use this and not [textField text];

Comment: OMG i never thought this will work out , but it did , Great. Thanks a Lot . +1 for u :) (y)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a controller A and you are pushing controller B on top of A.
So on calling popViewControllerAnimated in controller B

viewWillAppear:animated for controller A will be called

in your case B is RecherchePartenaireTableView, so there is no way viewWillAppear for B will be called on doing popViewController.

If you want to do something when RecherchePartenaireTableView disappears, do it in RecherchePartenaireTableView's viewWillDisappear

Comment: I want to set a text to a label after RecherchePartenaireTableView is called again..

Comment: You should use a model, cause you are saving state. IF you dont want to do that you can create a statevariable in appdelegeate, [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate stateVar] = someValue, and use this value in viewWillAppear for setting text

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated method will be called first
```

Comment: then why I don't get the message from NSLog?

Comment: IF that doesn't work you can use the UINavigationControllerDelegate method called - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;